# Speeding up contouring of .mrr files in Mapinfo?

Tags: mapinfo, performance, contour, multi-resolution-raster

I'm contouring relatively small 30m resolution grids - 50-100mb .mrr files.
Creating a simple 1 level contour takes hours! I let a slightly larger one run on a spare machine and it took days.

Is there any way I can speed this up?

Can I convert it back to .grd and contour it from there?

Can I change some settings in the contouring tool?

I'm using Mapinfo 15.2

edit: Contours ran for more than an hour, and didn't create valid output.
Ran it in Alteryx and it contoured in about 2 minutes, on a much slower machine. Still no idea why it takes so long in Mapinfo.

Comment: Depending on the application more ram and chipset speed can help. what are the specs of the processing machine?

Comment: The machine is a monster that's supposed to host 5 VMs but I've got the whole thing - 2 2.5 Xeon e5 2680 processors and 128gb of ram. SSD disks. It shouldn't have a problem creating a 3mb contour from a 100mb .mrr file.

Comment: That sounds odd. Have you tried zooming into a smaller area and limiting the contour to the extent of the map just to check if that works? Also try limiting the contouring to say a few intervals

Answer (score 1):

One thing that comes to mind is MapInfo preference setting for Memory Cache Size.
The default value for this option is "Low" which corresponds to memory size 1024 MB.
Choose any other cache size like Maximum.
Low = (1024 MB)
Normal = Max(50% System Memory, 2 GB)
High = Max(50% System Memory, 4 GB)
Maximum = Max(50% System Memory, 8 GB)

This would make MapInfo utilize the available memory of system.

P.S. For future visitors, this option can be accessed by
going to Pro Backstage then choosing Options tab then MapInfo Raster ->Preferences. A window will open, choose Memory And Performance tab.

Pro->Options->Raster-Preferences->Memory And Performance-> Memory Cache Size

Comment: Thanks! I don't have MapInfo anymore so I can't test it out, but I had never heard of that setting. I seem to recall seeing a hard cap on processors more than ram but it can't hurt...